# How can I extract the places values of a number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, multiplication

I'm working on a math game in the Unity game engine using C#, specifically a reusable component to teach the grid method for multiplication. For example, when given the numbers 34 and 13, it should generate a 3X3 grid (a header column and row for the multiplier and multiplicand place values and 2X2 for the number of places in the multiplier and multiplicand). Something that looks like this:

[image: Multiplication grid]

My issue is that I don't know the best way to extract the place values of the numbers (eg 34 -> 30 and 4). I was thinking of just converting it to a string, adding 0s to the higher place values based on its index, and converting it back to an int, but this seems like a bad solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

Note: I'll pretty much only be dealing with positive whole numbers, but the number of place values might vary.

---

Thanks to all who answered! Thought it might be helpful to post my Unity-specific solution that I constructed with all the replies:

```cs
List<int> GetPlaceValues(int num) {
    List<int> placeValues = new List<int>();
    while (num > 0) {
        placeValues.Add(num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<placeValues.Count;i++) {
        placeValues[i] *= (int)Mathf.Pow(10, i);
    }
    placeValues.Reverse();
    return placeValues;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use string interpolation?  Why does the output have to be numeric?

Comment: @Greg For the purposes of the component, I will eventually need to end up numeric to calculate the other parts of the grid (the 300,40,90,12).

Comment: what about % operator?

Comment: Think about what you're doing, and code to reality.  Isn't it nice that our numerical system has place value?  That you can read any single digit, and zero index from the decimal point, and simply multiply that digit times ten to that index's power?

Comment: @DavidRodriguez I've revised my earlier answer to actually produce a grid as you'd asked; this one took a little while! It's one of those things you expect to be easy until you end up having to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the way our number system works.  Here's a basic example:

```
string test = "12034";
for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; ++i) {
    int digit = test[test.Length - i - 1] - '0';
    digit *= (int)Math.Pow(10, i);
    Console.WriteLine("digit = " + digit);
}
```

Basically, it reads from the rightmost digit (assuming the input is an integer), and uses the convenient place value of the way our system works to calculate the meaning of the digit.

`test.Length - i - 1`   treats the rightmost as 0, and indexes positive to the left of there.

`- '0'` converts from the encoding value for '0' to an actual digit.

[Play with the code](https://ideone.com/IbDILK)

Comment: Accepted as answer, because it was the closest to what I was looking for. I used modulo to keep the number numerical.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez indeed, the Math.Pow stuff helped with my answer in getting the number with the correct zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is incredibly crude, and could likely be improved by someone with better maths skills:

```
void Main()
{
    GetMulGrid(34, 13).Dump();
}

int[,] GetMulGrid(int x, int y)
{
    int[] GetPlaceValues(int num)
    {
        var numDigits = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(num) + 1);
        var digits = num.ToString().ToCharArray().Select(ch => Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString())).ToArray();
        var multiplied =
            digits
            .Select((d, i) =>
            {
                if (i != (numDigits - 1) && d == 0) d = 1;
                return d * (int)Math.Pow(10, (numDigits - i) - 1);
            })
            .ToArray();
        return multiplied;
    }

    var xComponents = GetPlaceValues(x);
    var yComponents = GetPlaceValues(y);

    var arr = new int[xComponents.Length + 1, yComponents.Length + 1];

    for(var row = 0; row < yComponents.Length; row++)
    {
        for(var col = 0; col < xComponents.Length; col++)
        {
            arr[row + 1,col + 1] = xComponents[col] * yComponents[row];
            if (row == 0)
            {
                arr[0, col + 1] = xComponents[col];
            }
            if (col == 0)
            {
                arr[row + 1, 0] = yComponents[row];
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

For your example of 34 x 13 it produces:

[image: Basic grid]

And for 304 x 132 it produces:

[image]

It spits this out as an array, so how you consume and display the results will be up to you.

Comment: Wow, you went above and beyond. I was just looking for a method to extract the place values. +1 for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want something like this ([ideone](https://ideone.com/iIh9vF)):

```
int n = 76302;
int mul = 1;
int cnt = 0;
int res[10];

while(n) {
   res[cnt++] = (n % 10) * mul;
   mul*=10;
   cout << res[cnt-1] << " ";
   n = n / 10;
}

output 
2 0 300 6000 70000
```

Answer (score 1):

For two-digit numbers you can use modulo

```
int n = 34;
int x = n % 10;   // 4
int y = n - x;    // 30
```

Comment: Using modulo definitely seems like the cleanest solution. But I'll need it to handle a varying number of place values, not just two-digit numbers. I'll try to make a loop that changes the modulus each time through.

Comment: There's a general solution here that I haven't worked out yet.